# Set checkbox according to server response

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

A user can check/uncheck a checkbox and then it's value is saved into a DB:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="open" name="timeFormat[]" id="isCheckedFormat" checked>
```

This saved as: {`TimeFormat': [u'open']`}

When I call this back to the browser, console.log() it appears as: "[u'open']"

In [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58613zz1/23/), I try to use this to then set the users preferred setting but this doesn't set the checkbox to checked.

```
var x=[u&#39;open&#39;];

if (x=='open'){
    $('#isCheckedFormat').prop('checked', true);
}else{
$('#isCheckedFormat').prop('checked', false)
}
```

How can  the checkbox be set. Do I need to strip all the characters before and after 'open'....how could that be done?

Comment: Your response is not formatted properly. Either return plaintext "open", or return a JSON object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking that the string contains the word `open`, for instance...

```
var x="[u&#39;open&#39;];"
$('#isCheckedFormat').prop('checked', x.contains('open'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how are you sending how you are sending the response. but this will work for you:

```
if(x.indexOf("open") > -1)
  $('#isCheckedFormat').prop('checked', true);
else
  $('#isCheckedFormat').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex:

```
$('#isCheckedFormat').prop('checked', /open/.test(x));
```

You could also use [.indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

```
$('#isCheckedFormat').prop('checked', x.indexOf("open") != -1);
```